# NSDateFormatter BC/AD dates issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to figure out how to parse AD and BC dates with NSDateFormatter and why 0000 year fails parsing.

```
NSString *test1 = @"0000-01-01";
NSString *test2 = @"0001-01-01";
NSString *test3 = @"0002-01-01 AD";
NSString *test4 = @"0002-01-01 BC";

NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter1 setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSLog(@"test 1 - %@", [formatter1 dateFromString: test1]);
NSLog(@"test 2 - %@", [formatter1 dateFromString: test2]);

NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter2 setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd G"];

NSLog(@"test 3 - %@", [formatter2 dateFromString: test3]);
NSLog(@"test 4 - %@", [formatter2 dateFromString: test4]);
```

And that's what it returns:

```
2012-11-26 11:24:27.536 Test[1968:c07] test 1 - (null)
2012-11-26 11:24:28.615 Test[1968:c07] test 2 - 0001-12-31 22:21:00 +0000
2012-11-26 11:24:37.604 Test[1968:c07] test 3 - 0001-12-31 22:21:00 +0000
2012-11-26 11:24:45.738 Test[1968:c07] test 4 - 0003-12-31 22:21:00 +0000
```

As you can see it returns null for 0000 date and wrong dates for other variants.

Comment: But what about BC/AD years? They also return wrong date!

Comment: because the format set to the date formatter doesn't match that of the date strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%28year%29), year zero does not exist in the Anno Domini(AD) system usually used to number years in the Gregorian calendar and in its predecessor, the Julian calendar. In this system, the year 1 BC is followed by AD 1. However, there is a year zero in astronomical year numbering (where it coincides with the Julian year 1 BC) and in ISO 8601:2004 (where it coincides with the Gregorian year 1 BC) as well as in all Buddhist and Hindu calendars.

You cannot Log a date object correctly. Try converting the obtained date to string using stringFromDate function and log the output.